# Question about SPSiteDataQuery

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I want to look for "Published Documents" library in entire site collection and loop through. I found **SPSiteDataQuery** looks interesting but it needs **serverTemplate** id and if I pass **101** it will search all the document libraries but I want to restrict on specific library. How to do that ?

```
query.Lists = "<Lists ServerTemplate=\"101\" />";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will only search all the list libraries if you set:

```
SPSiteDataQuery query = new SPSiteDataQuery();
query.Webs = "<Webs Scope='SiteCollection' />";
```

or to get a recursive search:

```
query.Webs = "<Webs Scope='Recursive' />";
```

if you do not set the 'Webs' property it will just search the current Web (and list).